# Facebook Invite dialog not opening on mobile devices (iPhone/Android)

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

this is documented in two separated Facebook bugs

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17261

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17260

it has been a month, and Facebook has yet to fix it, my clients are very angry so I am looking for a workaround.

can I create an invite UI of my own and do some graph API calls to get invitations to be sent to selected friends ?

Comment: anyone ? this is very important

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately you are at the mercy of Facebook for this bug to get fixed, one of the risks of using a 3rd party platform for this.  There is no graph api for this as this functionality is only available via their social plugins.  The app requests / invitations too has been particularly volatile, having previously been removed and brought back in a different form (probably due to spamming/abuse).

Comment: thanks, what is your experience with Facebook with regards to getting bugs fixed ? whats the expected time frame ? do you know of a way to escalate things with them ?